# Virtualenv with different python version doesn't work on windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

i have Python 2.6 as my default python on Windows 7, and i'm trying to get a virtual env with Python 2.7

I have python 2.6 in C:\Python26, and python 2.7 in C:\Python27

When i try to use `virtualenv -p` i get this

```
C:\web\xxx>virtualenv -p "C:\Python27\python.exe" --no-site-packages venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Python27\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2577, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1081, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1277, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1215, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1185, in change_prefix
    (filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename C:\Python26\Lib\os.py does not start with any of these prefixes: ['C:\\Python27']
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run virtualenv with the python I want and don't use the -p option:

(edited to fix path)

```
C:\web\xxx>C:\Python27\python c:\path\to\virtualenv.py --no-site-packages venv
```

Comment: that seems to be a smart way to do it, but virtualenv is not installed for python27, only for python26. i get this
`C:\web\xxx>C:\Python27\python virtualenv --no-site-packages venv`

`C:\Python27\python: can't open file 'virtualenv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @avastreg - my bad, I should have used the entire path and extension for virtualenv.py. It's not version specific, so it should work with 2.7 as well as 2.6.